# Binding Values Correct Phone 8.1 Combobox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to fill a combobox in phone 8.1 not silverlight but having a issue.I am using the following to try and bind the cities to a drop down to choose and then save it using local storage for a settings page.

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popcornpk_Dal _dal = new popcornpk_Dal();
    CitysList _mycities = await _dal.GetCityListAsync();
    cmbocity.ItemsSource = _mycities.cityList;
}
```

This basically gets a list of all cities

```
public async Task<CitysList> GetCityListAsync()
{
    string jsonresult = await WCFRESTServiceCall("GET", "cinema_city");
    var jarray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CitysList>(jsonresult);
    return jarray;
}
```

My Xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbocity" Margin="20,117.75,0,465.25" SelectedValuePath="ItemDescription" Width="310" Height="Auto" FontSize="17"
   ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding timing_title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>



</Grid>

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton Label="Save" Icon="Save" Click="SaveSettings_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

My Class for the drop down is.

```
public class City
{
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string timing_title { get; set; }
}
public class CitysList
{
        public List<City> cityList { get; set; }
}
```

Ps I new in silverlight their used to be a settings flyout to build a settings page very easy using isloated storage is their such a thing for 8.1 Runtime

Comment: Could you state which part isn't working?

Comment: @jp2code sorry its just showing select an item no data yet when i debug through the webservice code the data is in the class fine

Comment: Why are you setting the ItemsSource property in XAML?

Comment: I thouhgt you had to do that to tell it to take from itemsource sure can give an example of how to set the values of combobox to above list ill mark as answer